# how to use brackets in a script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I create this silly script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#archivo=0
for i in *.esp.srt
do
  iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "$i.srt"

done
```

But I have to rename the files before in order to execute the script properly. If the file is called, for example:

"whatever" (Español (España)).srt

It doesn't work.

I already tried changing this line in my script:
    for i in *(Español (España)).srt

But obviously, I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't work.

Edit: my script works when the file is *.esp.srt.
But it doesn't work if the file is * (Español (España)).srt

Edit2: Now it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
#archivo=0
for i in *" (Español (España)).srt"
do
  iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "${i%% "(Español (España)).srt"}.esp.srt"
  rm *" (Español (España)).srt"
done
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can try running

```
detox *
```

before.

See http://detox.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
mkdir -p converted && \
for i in *.esp.srt *Esp*.srt
do
  iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "converted/$i"
done
```

Also, how do you really want your filenames converted? You should also know that with your code your outputs become `something.srt.srt`. If you like to replace your extension to something like .utf8.srt, do it this way (assuming your files end in .esp.srt):

```
for i in *.esp.srt
do
  iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "${i%%.esp.srt}.utf8.srt"
done
```

Similarly you could add another loop for files like `"whatever" .(Español (España)).srt`:

```
for i in *'.(Español (España)).srt'
do
  iconv -f=ISO8859-1 -t=UTF-8 "$i" > "${i%%'.(Español (España)).srt'}.utf8.srt"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your tip about the quotation marks is what I needed to run my script properly!

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: my script works when the file is *.esp.srt. But it doesn't work if the file is * (Español (España)).srt

Uhh yeah.  That's because this line

> for i in *.esp.srt

Only looks for things that end in `.esp.srt` which `"whatever" (Español (España)).srt` does not.  If you want to use

> for i in *(Español (España)).srt

Then you'll need to account for the brackets, as you imply.  Put `""` around it.